# why app.use() in js express might not work?

Tags: node.js, express, cors

I'm trying to handle CORS issue and add necessary strings to respond's headers:
`

```
var express = require('express');
const app = express();
var router = express.Router();

router.options('/*', function(req, res, next){
  app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
    next();
  });
  res.sendStatus(200);
  console.log(res.getHeaders());
});
```

`
But it doesn't work - console.log(res.getHeaders()) shows standard header:

```
[Object: null prototype] {
  'x-powered-by': 'Express',
  'content-type': 'text/plain; charset=utf-8',
  'content-length': '2',
  etag: 'W/"2-nOO9QiTIwXgNtWtBJezz8kv3SLc"'
}
```

What might prevent triggering this function?

In despair, I tried this construction:
`

```
router.options('/*', function(req, res, next){
  const respond = async function() {
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
  }
  respond()
  res.sendStatus(200);
  console.log(res.getHeaders());
});
```

`
And it does work:

```
[Object: null prototype] {
  'x-powered-by': 'Express',
  'access-control-allow-origin': '*',
  'access-control-allow-headers': 'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept',
  'content-type': 'text/plain; charset=utf-8',
  'content-length': '2',
  etag: 'W/"2-nOO9QiTIwXgNtWtBJezz8kv3SLc"'
}
OPTIONS /email 200 4.345 ms - 2
```

What I'm doing wrong and where to look for the error

Comment: I'm not an expert on express, but I don't think you're supposed to call app.use inside another handler, it should be called at setup, not per request.

Comment: I've tried to put it outside (before) routers - the result is the same.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson, I used express-generator to create the app, and, as a beginner, still confused about where to put this function or similar ones: to /bin/www or to app.js in the root directory. Actually, I tried to put the function everywhere with the same result :)

Comment: There's never a need to allow the `Origin` header.

Answer (score 0):

The `app.use` statement with the CORS handling middleware must come *before* the other middlewares. And such statements must all be on the top level, not nested in one another:

```js
const app = express();
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
  next();
});
var router = express.Router();
router.options('/*', function(req, res, next){
  res.sendStatus(200);
  console.log(res.getHeaders());
});
```

Your nested `app.use` statement is executed only when an incoming request is handled by the `router`. But by then it is too late, because this will effectively register the CORS handling middleware *last*.

Your desparate solution works because it does not involve registering a new middleware.

As an alternative to homegrown CORS handlers, you may want to consider the [`cors`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors) package.

Comment: the first thing I've done - tried your variant, but for some reason, it didn't work

Answer (score 0):

I found that I can put res.header(...) right into the body of the router, without using app.use():

```
router.options('/*', function(req, res, next){
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
    res.sendStatus(200);
    console.log(res.getHeaders());
});
```

and it works.
Probably, the solution was always on the surface, but I spent almost a day to get this :)